# Unable to connect to the report server 2008 r2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

-

i can't to connect report server

**PC config**
window 7, II7, sql sever 2008 R2

Reporting services configuration manager give error

when i connect to the server give this error

**Unable to connect to the report server [ServerName]**

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question belongs on http://serverfault.com but bare in mind that given its quality and the level of details provided chances are it will get closed pretty quickly there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the reporting services service started? services.msc from the start menu.

Answer (score -1):

You have not installed reporting services. When you will do it, you will see it listed in configuration manager.