# Unable to connect to report server 2012 rc0

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I get the same error as on this post: [Unable to connect to the report server 2008 r2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338172/unable-to-connect-to-the-report-server-2008-r2)

So I downloaded Reporting Services from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=29068

It seems like the only way for me to install reporting services is to select "Reporting Services - Native" in the Feature Selection phase of the SQL Server 2012 Setup. However when I did that before, my SQL server could not swap between Native and Integrated mode...but it ran solely in Native mode and I had to re-install SQL server and de-select "Reporting Services - Native" in the "Feature Selection". What I want is Integrated Mode as I want to run SQL Server 2012 on one box and SharePoint 2010 on another box. So how do I install reporting services on SQL Server 2012 (rc0)? Is selecting it in the "Feature Selection" the only way to do it? According to this site (see http://blogs.pointbridge.com/Blogs/burger_mike/Pages/Post.aspx?_ID=35#EntryTabs) you can just deselect this option "If you know that you are only going to use SSRS in SharePoint Integrated mode you can unselect the option to also install Reporting Services in Native mode" but if I do that I can't see the Reporting Services in SQL Server Configuration Manager. So what do I do?

Comment: Voting to close as off topic. Better fit for http://dba.stackexchange.com/